# найти минимальный элемент в каждой строке двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, матрицы

нужно найти минимальный элемент в каждой строке матрицы, я нахожу только один по всей матрице? как найти остальные и вывести их индексы и само значение?

```
import numpy as np
row = 5
a=np.array ([[0, 2.4, -6, 5, 0.8], 
             [1.5, 0, 0, -4.3, -3.5], 
             [0, 1.8, 3.2, -1.2, -1.3],
             [0, 0, -2.3, 0, -7.2],
             [3.3, -0.8, 0, 3.5, 8]])
min = np.min(a)
max = np.max(a)
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(row):
        if(a[i][j]<min):
            min=a[i][j]
        elif(a[i][j]>max):
            max=a[i][j]
print(min)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же используете numpy. Ну так и воспользуйтесь его инструментарием:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array ([[0, 2.4, -6, 5, 0.8], 
             [1.5, 0, 0, -4.3, -3.5], 
             [0, 1.8, 3.2, -1.2, -1.3],
             [0, 0, -2.3, 0, -7.2],
             [3.3, -0.8, 0, 3.5, 8]])
res = a.min(axis=1)
print(res)
```

> [-6.  -4.3 -1.3 -7.2 -0.8]

параметр `axis` указывает, где искать минимумы - 0 - строки, 1 - столбцы